# Kivy Update Label Text with Variable

Tags: python, text, label, scrollview, kivy

Question: How do I update Label text in this scenario?

Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

class SearchForPart(Widget):
    def searchforpart(self):
        Barty = 'text update';
        demogar = DemoGarage()
        demogar.ids.scrollref.UpdateParam(Barty)

class ScrollableLabel1(ScrollView):  
    text_variable_1 = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScrollableLabel1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text_variable_1 = 'initial' 

    def UpdateParam(self, param):
        self.param = param
        self.text_variable_1 = param
        print(param)

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class DemoGarage(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("garagemainexample.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Kv code:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    DemoGarage:

<BigButton@Button>:
    font_size: 40
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.15
    color: 0,1,0,1 

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        BigButton:
            on_release: app.root.current = "demogarage"
            text: "Demo Garage"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "top": 0.4} 

<DemoGarage>:
    name: "demogarage"
    ScrollableLabel1:
        id:scrollref
    SearchForPart:
        id:searchpart

<ScrollableLabel1>:
    Label:
        id: mylabel
        text: root.text_variable_1
        font_size: 20
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        padding_y: 10
        padding_x: 140

<SearchForPart>:
    size_hint: 1,1
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Search for Part:"
            font_size: 30
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.95, "y": 0.85}
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        TextInput:
            id: partname
            multiline: False
            font_size: 30
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.85, "y": 0.15}
            color: 0,1,0,1
            on_text_validate: root.searchforpart()
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
```

After initializing program, the Label text is successfully initialized and outputs 'initial text'.

Once the 'searchforpart' method runs (as a response to hitting enter in search box), even though 'print(param)' prints 'text update', the label text isn't updated.

Question: How do I update Label text in this scenario?

Am I misunderstanding a core concept of how changes to the Kivy event loop are triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Kivy property:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class (YourClass):
    text_variable_1 = StringProperty()
```

When you reference this property in kv, and its value changes, the gui will automatically update. If you don't use a property this doesn't happen because the kv code has no way to know the value changed.

Also, you don't have to follow pep8, but the property name should start with a lower case letter - it probably doesn't matter for your example, but can matter in kv if you try to set the property there.

Comment: I took your suggestions and updated my question above. Unfortunately, the problem still remains.

Comment: I think your use of the global keyword may be wrong. I'd try doing it without using a global variable like that, since it isn't necessary anyway.

Comment: I've updated my question again after taking your advice to remove global variables. However, label text still fails to update.

Comment: I've been stuck on this particular problem for days now. Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated. I've tried switching out python class variables with kv variables (using ids), but am having what looks to be the same type of issue: variable updates, but GUI doesn't.

Comment: Your example only calls UpdateParam for a new ScrollableLabel1 that doesn't have anything to do with your gui. You need to call the method for the ScrollableLabel1 that you're actually displaying in your app.

Comment: I've updated the posted question in response to your suggestion of calling the specific method tied to the GUI. 'DemoGarage' is indeed the parent screen displaying ScrollableLabel1's text output, but even though I'm now calling for that specific method, GUI is still not updating (Note: print(param) is still working)

Comment: You're still doing the same thing, except now you're creating a new DemoGarage instance. Post a runnable minimal example demonstrating the problem, instead of just some code snippets.

Comment: Alright, I've updated the post such that provided code is minimal, yet fully runnable. Thanks again.

Comment: I suppose the fundamental question here is: how do I update an existing method rather than just create a new instance of that method?

Comment: You need to ask what is the relationship between your widgets. In this case, the `DemoGarage` you care about is the parent of the `SearchForPart` widget, so you can access it as `self.parent` from a method of the `SearchForPart`. Therefore, you can change `demogar.ids.scrollref.UpdateParam(Barty)` to `self.parent.ids.scrollref.UpdateParam(Barty)`.

Comment: thank you!! This is the answer I've been looking for for eons.